# How do I load a font

Tags: java, javafx, fonts

I'm trying to load my own font. I tried the following:

```
Font font = Font.loadFont(MenuView.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/font/niagra_eng.TTF"), 100);
```

This worked just fine. But as soon as I make a new package, and move this class away from the default package, it doesn't work anymore. I also tried:

```
Font font = Font.loadFont("res/font/niagra_eng.TTF", 100);
```

but this font is null for some reason, and I'm sure that the path is correct since it worked when I used the other method.
And I'm using Javafx if it makes any difference.

This is where the font is uploaded

[image]

Comment: Why did you remove the classLoader to resolve the path?

Comment: It did not work with the classloader, and I tried a couple of things, and removing the classloader was one of them. Just to try something, not any specific reason.

Comment: Can you post an image or show the layout of your project?

Comment: sorry, you're showing code in isolation, what are you talking about when you talk about moving classes from packages? Where is the *rest* of the code that is relevant here? In particular, can you please show a [mcve]? Without actual details, I'm going to assume you did not make sure that `getResourcesAsStream` is resolving to the correct absolute location, given the relatively location in your code.